How do I persist S3 buckets across restarts in localstack?
I am having trouble persisting S3 buckets (and their contents) across restarts in my localstack deployment on my dev machine.
This is my docker-compose.yaml file
version: "3.8"

services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME:-localstack-main}"
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"            # LocalStack Gateway
      - "127.0.0.1:4510-4559:4510-4559"  # external services port range
    environment:
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG:-0}
      - PERSISTENCE=1
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: D:/web/Localstack/data
        target: /var/lib/localstack
      - type: bind
        source: /var/run/docker.sock
        target: /var/run/docker.sock

Is this possible/supported in localstack?

Yes, it is. However to enable persistence you need localstack/localstack-pro image.
